Pass dictionary and return from pl/sql
What is the proper way to pass a dictionary from python to pl/sql anonymous block?
Pl/sql need to receive data from dictionary, loop over keys and return a list of keys and counter variable, but I dont understand how.
Code below returns

oracledb.exceptions.NotSupportedError: DPY-3002: Python value of type "dict_items" is not supported

with connection.cursor() as cur:

    # sample dictionary
    d_data = {'111': 'YES', 
              '222': 'NO', 
              '333': 'YES'}

    cur.execute("""\
        DECLARE

        TYPE d_icusnums_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
        d_icusnums d_icusnums_type;
        
        BEGIN
            FOR key_val IN :data LOOP
                d_icusnums('key_val.key') := 'key_val.value';
            END LOOP;

        END;
        """, data=d_data.items())


Looking at the Python OracleDB - Binding PL/SQL Collections documentation:

PL/SQL Collections like Associative Arrays can be bound as IN, OUT, and IN/OUT variables. When binding IN values, an array can be passed directly as shown in this example, which sums up the lengths of all of the strings in the provided array. First the PL/SQL package definition:
create or replace package mypkg as

    type udt_StringList is table of varchar2(100) index by binary_integer;

    function DemoCollectionIn (
        a_Values            udt_StringList
    ) return number;

end; /

create or replace package body mypkg as

    function DemoCollectionIn (
        a_Values            udt_StringList
    ) return number is
        t_ReturnValue       number := 0;
    begin
        for i in 1..a_Values.count loop
            t_ReturnValue := t_ReturnValue + length(a_Values(i));
        end loop;
        return t_ReturnValue;
    end;

end; /

Then the Python code:
values = ["String One", "String Two", "String Three"] 
return_val = cursor.callfunc("mypkg.DemoCollectionIn", int, [values])
print(return_val)        # will print 32


This assumes (as do all the other documentation examples) that the value being passed is a collection with a numeric index where the input is effectively an array and not a dictionary.
Therefore, it appears that passing dictionaries is not supported.

As an alternative, you can convert your dictionary to key-value pairs and pass those as an array of records:
CREATE PACKAGE data_types AS
  TYPE key_value_pair IS RECORD (
    key   VARCHAR2(100),
    value VARCHAR2(100)
  );

  TYPE key_value_list IS TABLE OF key_value_pair INDEX BY binary_integer;
END;
/

Then:
with connection.cursor() as cur:
    # sample dictionary
    d_data = {'111': 'YES', '222': 'NO', '333': 'YES'}

    key_value_pair_type = connection.gettype("DATE_TYPES.KEY_VALUE_PAIR")
    key_value_list = []

    for key, value in d_data.items():
        kvp = key_value_pair_type.newobject()
        kvp.KEY = key
        kvp.VALUE = value
        key_value_list.append(kvp)
      

    cur.execute("""
DECLARE
  TYPE d_icusnums_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
  d_icusnums d_icusnums_type;
BEGIN
  FOR key_val IN :data LOOP
    d_icusnums(key_val.key) := key_val.value;
  END LOOP;

  -- do something with d_icusnums
END;
""",
        [key_value_list]
    )


It is necessary to create package or I can do type creation inside anonymous plsql block?
And how return list of dictionary keyes from plsql block back to python?

@ChainSaw You need to be able to get the type information from the database before executing the query therefore you cannot define the type in a local PL/SQL block; it must be in a PL/SQL package.

How to return d_icusnums dictionary from plsql?

@ChainSaw I do not understand what you are asking. You already have the dictionary in Python, why would you want to send it to the database and then return it back to Python? Just use it as-is in Python without sending it to the database if you want to use it in Python. If you have an associative array that is indexed by a number (not a string) then the documentation linked in the question shows you how to read it back to a Python list (and not to a dictionary). If you have a string-indexed associative array then the documentation does not cover that scenario and it may not be possible.

I will do some process inside plsql (not shown in my example). If process with key return True result, then key from python dictionary is Ok and must be returned to python like that: result = { 'key1':True}. This way I can understand that the function processed the key  in plsql blick successfully.

@ChainSaw If the cx_oracle/python-oracledb database driver does not support string-indexed associative arrays then convert your dictionary to a list where each key is in an odd index and each corresponding value is in the next even index and then return that list - then you can rebuild the dictionary in Python from that list of pairs. Alternatively, use data_types.key_value_pair and data_types.key_value_list and return that.
